# How to join an entity object with select query in LINQ c#

Tags: c#, sql, linq, join, sql-to-linq-conversion

```
select * from ABC a left outer join (select * from XYZ x)y on a.ID = y.ID
```

How to convert above query to LINQ (c#)

Comment: I'm confused by your SQL. Are you trying to accomplish this - `SELECT * FROM ABC a LEFT OUTER JOIN XYZ x ON a.ID = x.ID`? I'm unsure why you're adding a sub-query?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this.

```
from a in ABC
join y in (from x in XYZ select x ) on a.ID equals y.ID into temp
from z in temp.DefaultIfEmpty()
select z
```